# Suave and DotLiquid

Tags: f#, suave, dotliquid

*edited for clarity*

somehow this works:

```
path "/" >=> warbler (fun _ -> OK (string DateTime.Now))
```

but this one does not:

```
let txnAccA =
    let sqlStr = "select JSON from Store.Txn"
    let result = Db.execute sqlStr Config.oConnStr
    match result with
    | Some a ->
        [for i in a do 
            let msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TxnAccA>(i)
            yield msg
            ]

    | _ ->
        List.empty<TxnAccA>

let txnAmtA =
    let sqlStr = "select JSON from Store.Amt"
    let result = Db.execute sqlStr Config.oConnStr
    match result with
    | Some a ->
        [for i in a do 
            let msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TxnAmtA>(i)
            yield msg
            ]

    | _ ->
        List.empty<TxnAmtA>

let result ()= {Acc= txnAccA; Amt= txnAmtA}
path "/txn" >=> warbler (fun _ -> page "txn.html" (result()))
```

By "works" I mean that the page is not static, it displays latest data from database. Any idea why?

Comment: Where are `txnAcc` and `txnAmt` defined? It's very possible that the way you've defined them is the problem (i.e., they're only getting set once), but we'll need to see that part of your code to know for sure.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Tomas, no error. just that the page keep displaying the same data, even though records in db have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txnAccA` and `txnAmtA` need to be functions (similar to `result`). They are defined as values now, so get assigned once and will not query the DB for every request. `result` will create a new record every time when called, but the values stay always the same.

```
let txnAccA () = //...

let txnAmtA () = //...

let result () = { Acc = txnAccA(); Amt = txnAmtA() }
path "/txn" >=> warbler (fun _ -> page "txn.html" (result()))
```